# If $f$ is a group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ to $(\mathbb{Q}-\{0\},.)$ such that $f(2)=\frac{1}{3}$, then find $f(-8)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I came across the following question:

If $f$ is a group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ to $(\mathbb{Q}-\{0\},.)$ such that $f(2)=\frac{1}{3}$, then what is the value of $f(-8)$?

By property of group homomorphism, we can write - $f(8) = f(2+2+2+2) = f(2)^4 = \frac{1}{81}$.

But we are asked to find $f(-8)$. How does the negative sign change the answer (i.e. if it changes, I am not sure)?

Thank you.

Comment: $1=f(0)=f(-8+8)=f(-8)f(8)$

Comment: I am not sure you are applying the rules for a group homomorphism correctly. f(8)=f(2+2+2+2)=f(2)^4.

Comment: To strengthen mich95's hint, if $f$ is a homomorphism of groups, what is $f(-x)$?

Comment: @OnceUponACrinoid I edited the post. Is it oky now?

Comment: @Tani Thanks. I was attempting a bunch of questions on abstract algebra for exams, I found this in those...

Comment: @Ritu: Actually I want to know the name of the text if the Qn is from any Text.

Comment: @Tani No, I didn't find it in any text.  It was in a question bunch given by our proffesor.

Comment: @Ritu: O.K....Thank u

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $$f(x)f(-x)=f(x-x)=f(0)=1$$ by the homomorphism property then $f(-x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to ask another thing. I can see that this property is true here. Is it true in general for all homomorphisms?

Comment: @Ritu: Yes. If $f$ is a homomorphism then $f(x^{-1}) = f(x)^{-1}$ (I have used multiplicative notation so that we don't worry about commutativity). The proof is the same as the one Thomas gave, only with the different notation.

Answer (score 4):

This question is intentionally confusing.

The fact that it's a group homomorphism means $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$, since the domain is an additive group, and the codomain is a multiplicative group. Thus actually,

$f(8)=f(2+2+2+2)=f(2)f(2)f(2)f(2)=\frac{1}{81}$.

Since $1=f(0)=f(8-8)=f(8)f(-8)$, $f(-8)=\frac{1}{f(8)}=81$.

Comment: Thank you...:) I got confused. I edited the post...